# Python what does > sign

Tags: python, scikit-image

I recently found this part of code:
`filteredImage = image > filters.threshold_otsu(image)`

In most languages `image > filters.threshold_otsu(image)` would return `true` or `false`. In this case `filteredImage` is `ndarray`. So what exactly happens in this code?

Comment: Its creates a boolean mask doing element wise comparison.

Comment: I don't know what kind of knowledge / background you have, but this operation is completely linked/depending to/on numpy. So i highly recommend their tutorial / docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python allows operator overloading. So you'd best consult the documentation for your particular use case - here its a boolean mask as the comments have pointed out, but python allows you to use any operator to do almost anything you like.

For example, you could have a class that uses `>` to decide if one array is longer than another array if you implemented your own array class. The best thing to do would be to search the documentation for your particular use case and look for operators.

## Further Clarification

Imagine I made a class called train, that just holds a string, and I wanted to use `>` to stick two trains together. (looks like it would be nice to do that :P)

```
class Train:

    def __init__(self, cargo):
        self.cargo = cargo

    def __call__(self):
        print("__{0}__".format(self.cargo))

    def __gt__(self, another):
        self.cargo = "{0}__{1}".format(self.cargo, another.cargo)

# Make two trains
a = Train("check")
b = Train("me")
a()
b()

# Join the trains and print again
a > b
a()
b()
```

Which would output

```
__check__
__me__
__check__me__
__me__
```

Notice that I didn't use this to return true or false, and I didn't even make the operator return anything. It would be important for me to document this in any documentation I provide to tell you what my intended use case for the `>` symbol is for my class.

This is a hugely useful feature that gets used all the time (eg multiplication in the numpy library - python can't natively multiply numpy.arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Since you point out its an ndarray, numpy uses vectorized implementation of element wise comparision and returns a boolean mask which will also be a numpy array. An example :

```
a = np.array([1,2,7,8,9])

b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

a <= b

array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Which is almost equivalent to below if done using for loop for 1D array :

```
k = []
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    k.append(i<=j)
k = np.array(k)

array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Numpy support almost all operators.  For more info and logic function you can check [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html)